# Почему плагины мультиязычности дублируют контент страниц?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf, polylang

Пытаюсь сделать мультиязычность на сайте с CMS Wordpress, но плагины дублируют контент на все переводы.

Установил плагин Polylang создаю 2 версии главной страницы на украинском и английском языках. При редактировании контента одной страницы например украинского языка эти изменения почему-то дублируются так же на другие локали. Т.е. при заходе на главную страницу других языков - там контент украинской версии. Так же все меняется в редактировании этих страниц.

Информация заполняется в кастомные поля плагина ACF. Получается дублируются значения полей ACF.

Пробовал ставить плагин WP Globus, WP Multilang - тоже самое.

В чем может быть проблема ? Такое происходит только с контеном, заполненным через кастомные поля.
Контент заполенный через стандартные поля корректно переводится.

Почитал, вроде все плагины корретно работают с ACF, тогда в чем может быть причина ?

Comment: У меня та же проблема, но только с главной страницей.
Установлен Полиленг. Уже перекопал кучу форумов, но решения так и не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, все оказалось до безобразия просто:

Если до мультиязычности ACF выводились через конструкцию:

```
<? the_field('some-field', ID); ?>
```

Где ID - ID страницы, с которой берется значение.

То при переводе других страниц, у них другие ID (что логично). Конструкцию выше нужно было просто переделать в следующую:

```
<? the_field('some-field', pll_get_post(ID)); ?>
```

Где ID - та же страница (которая берется с основного языка).

Это позволит вывести для нужного языка связанную версию страницы, а так же необходимую нам информацию.

Comment: Вот именно поэтому вопросы без кода не приветствуются. Кто мог подумать, что вы не знаете о том, что у переведённых страниц другой ID. Главное требование к вопросам здесь - создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Для перевода полей ACF нужен Polylang PRO или WPML с дополнительным плагином ACFML.

Comment: с Polylang PRO тоже самое. Так же пробовал ставить ACF Pro - все одинаково.

Comment: Что-то делаете неправильно.